# PCL: How to delete deviations from a point cloud?

Tags: c++, cluster-analysis, point-cloud-library

I got a pointcloud where most points are very near together representing an object. This pointcloud was derived from a segmentation of an image with a depth sensor. Because of some inaccuracies the pointcloud has also some points with some distance to the rest. like an own little cluster of points. You can see these points outlined in red here:

[image]

Now I would like to delete these points for further processing of the pointcloud. What would be the best approach to do so? I thought about doing some clustering using a clustering algorithm like `k-means`. But when doing so I would need to know the number of clusters beforehand. And because this pointcloud is derived from a sensor, I am not always having these points I want to erase. Sometimes there is a cluster, sometimes there are more of them.

Is there any recommended way to solve this problem?

I would love any input. Thanks.

PS: I am using c++ and the pcl library.

Comment: well, you yourself say `representing **an** object`. Why not say you only want 1 cluster? This is kind of like a 3-D version of the image erosion operation. Maybe you can start with pixels that do not contain adjacent neighbors (adjacency being a setting you choose)?

Comment: @thatrobotguy You are right, I only want one cluster. Problem is, the pixels in the smaller clusters do have adjacent neighbors.

Comment: Well, look for more than 1 neighbor: in fact, try more than 1, like 8 or 9. WIth a 3D cube, there are 27-1 neighbors, so you need to be more discriminatory against pixels - scratch that - VOXELS - to find the object you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest trying out the statistical outlier filter built into PCL: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/statistical_outlier.php

You should be able to literally copy that example into your code and it will clear those sparse points for you (after changing the two hard-coded values to fit your scene).  If you will always be looking at the same scene or similar scenes, that will suffice.  If however you need a more generic solution that will adapt to variably noisy or sparse point clouds I would suggest you do the nearest neighbor histogram beforehand (in the code) and then do some simple peak analysis to set your standard deviation on the filter.

After applying this filter clustering should become trivial as the sparse points will be removed and any sparse bridges between clusters will also be targeted for deletion.

Although there are multiple solutions for clustering, in this case I would probably go for euclidean cluster extraction (you probably don't need to do the voxel grid as a pre step shown in the example since your cloud is inherently well spaced due to your sensor): http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/cluster_extraction.php

The cluster tolerance variable will allow you to specify exactly how far apart points can be to be included in the same cluster.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. As a lack of my english skills I just didn't find the documentation about statistical outliers. After successfully implementing the idea of @lenik  I tried this code and it works like a charm. It seems like I don't need to do any clustering at all after the filtering. Now I just need to figure out how to derive the right still hard coded values because my scene is changing a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, you have 1000 points, start from the first point, find all neighbours and put them in the same group, including the neighbours of the neighbours and so on. With whatever left, pick another point, create another group. Eventually you'll split all points into several groups, choose the largest one, drop the rest (or use some kind of threshold of group size, that should be dropped -- this depends on your data and you may decide this yourself).

Comment: That is a great idea. I will try to implement this and try it out. Thanks!

Comment: Although I can't say this is explicitly wrong, it doesn't leverage any of the built in functionality of PCL which is a very well fleshed out library and has multiple tools that will solve this problem rather than trying to re-invent the wheel.

Comment: Just to confirm. I actually implemented this idea and it worked :) Thanks for this input!